# Excel formula to lookup value from range where 1 criteria is a match and the second criteria is date between two values

Tags: excel, date, indexing, excel-formula, match

Using Office 2019.

I need to lookup a Rate from a table identified by two criteria (Emp ID and Effive Date).

The table contains a list of Emp ID and Rates based on Effective Date.  The Rate is in effect from the Effective Date until the next Effective Date.

[image: Table]

The formula needs to lookup a specific date from a report and find the Rate that was in effect on that date for that Emp ID.

The report provides the Emp ID, and specific transaction date, and the hours work on that date.  I need to query the table to pull the correct rate for the correct Emp ID.

[image: Report]

I have tried a series of array INDEX/MATCH formulas but have not figured out how to isolate the correct row where the Tran Date finds the newest Effective Date that is earlier than the Tran Date.

I was using

```
{INDEX(Table[Rate],MATCH(1,(Table[Emp ID]=A2)*(Year(Table[Effective Date])=Year(B2)),0))}
```

Where A2 is the Emp from the report and B2 is the Tran Date from the report. But the issue arises when an Emp ID has more than one Rate in a single year.

Comment: Likely using `SUMIFS`.

Comment: You could try this formula : `=LOOKUP(2,1/((E2=$A$2:$A$14)*(F2>$B$2:$B$14)),$C$2:$C$14)` where `E2` is `Emp ID` & `F2` is `Trans Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have commented above, this can be achieved using `LOOKUP()` function or with `INDEX()` with `MATCH()` function. Refer the following approaches, without using any auxiliary columns.

You can use either of the one, but based on your Excel Version, you may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when using the `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` approach.

[image]

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((E2=$A$2:$A$14)*(F2>$B$2:$B$14)),$C$2:$C$14)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `I2`

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$14,MATCH(1,1/((E2=$A$2:$A$14)*(F2>$B$2:$B$14)),1))
```

---

Comment: I've not used the LOOKUP function before.  Not understanding how the formula is working (I will do more research into this) but the solution seems to be just what I was looking for!  Thanks.

Comment: `LOOKUP()` function performs an approximate match, the default behavior makes it useful for solving certain problems like yours in `Excel`. You can read more here about the function. **[Here](https://exceljet.net/functions/lookup-function)**

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, you can consolidate the values in a single index. Create a new column `[Index]` with the formula

```
=TEXT(Table[Emp ID],"000") & TEXT(Table[Effective Date],"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

where it is important that you put the employee id first and that you put the date in the reversed/ISO format, so this index will sort in the correct way.

You can then lookup using this index:

```
=XLOOKUP(
    TEXT($A2,"000") & TEXT($B2,"YYYY-MM-DD"),
    Table[Index], Table[Rate],,
    -1
 )
```

where `-1` means that the smaller item is returned, if there is no exact match.

If you do not have `XLOOKUP()` in your version, this can be done with `VLOOKUP()` as well.